# remove string only if it word, not part of other string

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to 'clean' my products names from something like 'blackberry Z3 64GB black' to 'blackberry Z3' 
I have an array of words and i use str_ireplace to remove them. The problem occurs is that when i remove the word 'black' it is also removed from the **black**berry. I need to remove the word ONLY if it is a word and not part of another word. Maybe regex?

Any suggestions?

Comment: use word boundaries `\bblack\b`

Comment: is there an easy way without regex?